# MinGW/Eclipse C building problem: cannot find dll

Tags: c, eclipse, gcc, build, mingw

I am trying to build my C project, which uses methods from a DLL, but I can't get it to work.

I keep having the following error:

```
**** Internal Builder is used for build               ****
gcc -oLibspotifyTest.exe main.o -lC:\Users\nbarraille\workspace\LibspotifyTest\lib\libspotify.dll
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.5.2/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lC:\Users\nbarraille\workspace\LibspotifyTest\lib\libspotify.dll
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
Build error occurred, build is stopped
Time consumed: 543  ms.
```

It says it cannot find my dll, but it is at the specified path.

I'm using Eclipse Helios with CDT, the latest version of MinGW, on windows 7.

My project hierarchy is the following:

```
LibspotifyTest
  Includes
    C:/MinGW/include
    C:/MinGW/lib/gcc/mingw32/4.5.2/include
    C:/MinGW/lib/gcc/mingw32/4.5.2/include-fixed
    LibspotifyTest/include
  Debug
  include
    api.h
  lib
    libspotify.dll
    libspotify.lib
  Release
    main.o
  main.c
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't you have to specify the .lib and not .dll? - so for -l it will  `libspotify.lib`  and not `libspotify.dll`

gcc -oLibspotifyTest.exe main.o -lC:\Users\nbarraille\workspace\LibspotifyTest\lib\libspotify.lib

Comment: I tried, but I have the same problem : "cannot find -lC:\Users\nbarraille\workspace\LibspotifyTest\lib\libspotify.lib"

Answer (score 0):

When specifying full paths to libraries you omit the `-l`, eg:

```
gcc -o LibspotifyTest.exe main.o C:\foo\lib\libspotify.lib
```